# Get Instance of HubContext for re-use anywhere At SelfHosted Asp.net core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I have got a self hosted asp.net core app working at console. I can send message  from my c# windows forms clients. But i want to send message anywhere in my server class to clients. Not one time message. So I need hubcontext instance for re-use it.

I have used IHubContext implement but im getting NullReference exception when I use hub context.

This is my Hub.

```
 public class UniveraHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
{
    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

}
```

This is my Startup Class

```
   public class Startup
{

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<UniveraHub>("/UniveraHub");
        });


    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddScoped<MyHubHelper>();
    }
}
```

This is my HubHelper Class

```
 public class MyHubHelper 
{
    private readonly IHubContext<UniveraHub> _hubContext;

    public MyHubHelper(IHubContext<UniveraHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public MyHubHelper()
    {

    }

    public void SendOutAlert(string msg)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedMessage", msg);
    }
}
```

This program.cs that I'm using my helper class for send message to clients

```
  MyHubHelper helper = new MyHubHelper();
  helper.SendOutAlert("Hi from server!");
```

Comment: Chances are your empty `MyHubHelper` constructor is being used, which will leave `_hubConext` as `null`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin so what i have to do ? Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to remove your empty constructor and and pass in `IHubContext<UniveraHub>` when you create an instance. Really, you shouldn't be creating your own instance of `MyHubHelper` - it should be resolved from the DI container.

Comment: @KirkLarkin this is the problem man i dont know how can i resolve my MyHubHelper class from DI container. Could you give me some example?

Comment: @KirkLarkin if i remove empty ctor its wants HubContext so where can i find and give it ?

Comment: See Ali's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `Program.cs` you can use like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
                    .Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var helper = services.GetRequiredService<MyHubHelper>();
            helper.SendOutAlert("Hi from server!");
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Hi, im getting 'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'CreateScope' and no accessible extension method 'CreateScope' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) error

Comment: its fixed when added using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; But how can i call my send message method at Helper Class? if i create new instance its giving null error again.

Comment: You don't have to create new instance of the class. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I need HubContext instance and this is not best way what i want bro.

Comment: Please update the question with the way you are using it and where you get the error.